# OHAttributedLabel works perfectly fine on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uilabel

I am using NSTextCheckingResult class to show text as links. I am using this [OHAttributedLabels](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) to work with it.

I want detection only for phone numbers and email id. That is I only want Phone numbers and email ids to get highlighted as links

Now the problem is that the below code works perfectly fine for iPad but not for iPhone:

```
self.automaticallyAddLinksForType = NSTextCheckingTypeDate|NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
```

But the same code shows even 5 digit ZipCodes as as a link in iPhone. It works perfectly fine in iPad. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of the OHAttributedLabel class. Thanks for using it!

As already answered directly to you by email, **`OHAttributedLabel` uses Apple's `NSDataDetector` class** to automatically detect links on a text.

So if there are misrecognised links, especially false positives, **that's due to Apple's `NSDataDetector` implementation** (and `OHAttributedLabel` can't do much for this, unfortunately). *The only thing that seems strange is that the `NSDataDetector` does not detect the same links on iPad and iPhone…*

---

**The only workaround** you can implement, if you are not satisfied with links found by Apple's `NSDataDetector`, is to remove the `NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber` value from `automaticallyAddLinksForType` and find the links on your own, for example using the `NSRegularExpression`'s class.

Anyway if you intend to, be careful as detecting the phone numbers manually is not trivial and kinda tricky. Especially, the format of phone numbers depends on the country the phone number is for (US phones are not formatted the same as French or UK ones), they may be formatted using spaces or dashes (or not), they can be in international format (+336 07...) and so on…

*Actually, that's probably because of this complexity that Apple's `NSDataDetector` can't avoid false positive matches…*

HTH

Comment: As a possible explanation for the difference of `NSDataDetector`'s behavior between the iPhone and iPad, maybe your devices don't use the same NSLocale. Check in your devices' settings (General > International) if your Language, Region Format and Calendar are the same, because **maybe** `NSDataDetector` uses them to determine the phone number format to detect?!

Answer (score 1):

Try just below line because I run code successfully and also works in iPhone.

```
label2.automaticallyAddLinksForType = NSTextCheckingTypeDate|NSTextCheckingTypeAddress|NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
```

Comment: I think it still does not show properly. I still shows links for all after implementing your answer I get links for email, address, 5 digit zip code, phone, fax

Comment: Do you have a more better solution?